# Freebase response always returns 403

Tags: google-api

We are experiencing difficulties with the Freebase API. Everything was working fine until few days ago when we started sending more queries. We breached the 10 queries/second limit and started getting 403 errors for some requests - the others were valid. The API key was included in the request.

We added a timer in order to limit our system to send less than 10 queries per second but the next day all requests were 403 forbidden, even when we sent a single search query. We did not get any notifications about the key begin invalid and also generated a new API key but it did not fix the problem. But if we copy and paste the url into the browser, the results are what they are supposed to be if the proxy has an automatic configuration. If we manually set the proxy to the same address as in the automatic configuration, we keep receiving 403 errors.

We tried sending a request from a different IP address using the same API key and the results were ok in the beginning but after a few queries we kept getting 403s again.

Another unusual behavior is that in our account we do not see the Freebase quota. We see the Custom Search API and YouTube Data API v3 quotas regularly.

Any ideas on what could be the source of the problem?

Here is the response we keep getting:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   { 
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "userRateLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
 }
}
```

EDIT: It seems that in the request the key query parameter was "KEY" instead of "key" resulting in unauthenticated request which caused our IP address to become temporarily banned.